# Cloud Dataflow to BigQuery - too many sources

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a job that among other things also inserts some of the data it reads from files into BigQuery table for later manual analysis.

It fails with the following error:

```
job error: Too many sources provided: 10001. Limit is 10000., error: Too many sources provided: 10001. Limit is 10000.
```

What does it refer to as "source"? Is it a file or a pipeline step?

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the error is coming from BigQuery and means that we are trying to upload too many files when we create your output table.

Could you provide some more details on the error / context (like a snippet of the commandline output (if using the BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner) so I can confirm? A jobId would also be helpful.

Is there something about your pipeline structure that is going to result in a large number of output files? That could either be a large amount of data or perhaps finely sharded input files without a subsequent GroupByKey operation (which would let us reshard the data into larger pieces).

Comment: This happened to me when I was reading the input from more than 10k files and planned to immediately persist the records in BigQuery without applying other transforms.

Comment: In that case each file is going to create at least one work item, and each work item will result in an temporary file that needs to get uploaded into the final BQ table. 

We'll look into working around that on our end. In the meantime, there are two basic workarounds:

1. Read <10000 files into one PCollection, process it, and write to BQ. Then repeat for more output files. These operations will still be parallelizable, though writing the output table will no longer happen as an atomic operation. This only works because you don't need to do any aggregation across all your values.

Comment: 2. A less efficient work around is to force a GroupByKey, which will likely give the system a chance to reshard the data into fewer work units. 
  a. ParDo to transform each record into (record, null)
  b. GroupByKey
  c. ParDo to transform each (record, [null, ..., null]) into record, ..., record

Comment: Here's how I implemented the GroupByKey suggestion, in case it helps anyone. I used 1 instead of null just because it was easier to set the type. The elements of my PCollection are strings. Apologies for the formatting

  ```.apply(MapElements.via((String event) -> KV.of(event, 1)).withOutputType(new TypeDescriptor<KV<String, Integer>>() {}))

  .apply(GroupByKey.<String, Integer>create())

  .apply(Keys.<String>create())```

Answer (score 1):

The note in In [Google Cloud Dataflow BigQueryIO.Write occur Unknown Error (http code 500)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391999/google-cloud-dataflow-bigqueryio-write-occur-unknown-error-http-code-500) mitigates this issue:

> Dataflow SDK for Java 1.x: as a workaround, you can enable this experiment in : --experiments=enable_custom_bigquery_sink
>
> In Dataflow SDK for Java 2.x, this behavior is default and no experiments are necessary.
>
> Note that in both versions, temporary files in GCS may be left over if your job fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class ForceGroupBy <T> extends PTransform<PCollection<T>, PCollection<KV<T, Iterable<Void>>>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public PCollection<KV<T, Iterable<Void>>> apply(PCollection<T> input) {
        PCollection<KV<T,Void>> syntheticGroup = input.apply(
                ParDo.of(new  DoFn<T,KV<T,Void>>(){
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    @Override
                    public void processElement(
                            DoFn<T, KV<T, Void>>.ProcessContext c)
                                    throws Exception {
                        c.output(KV.of(c.element(),(Void)null));

                    } }));
        return syntheticGroup.apply(GroupByKey.<T,Void>create());
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would really be helpful in this case - what is this code doing and how does it address the question? This is also helpful to avoid people copying this code and then running into errors.