# Error: Message: Too many sources provided: 15285. Limit is 10000

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm currently trying to run a Dataflow (Apache Beam, Python SDK) task to import a >100GB Tweet file into BigQuery, but running into `Error: Message: Too many sources provided: 15285. Limit is 10000.`

The task takes the tweets (JSON), extracts 5 relevant fields, transforms/sanitizes them a bit with some transforms and then write those values into BigQuery, which will be used for further processing.

There's [Cloud Dataflow to BigQuery - too many sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775920/cloud-dataflow-to-bigquery-too-many-sources) but it seems to be caused by having a lot of different input files, whereas I have a single input file, so it doesn't seem relevant. Also the solutions mentioned there are rather cryptic and I'm not sure if/how I could apply them to my problem.

My guess is that BigQuery writes temporary files for each row or something before persisting them, and that's what's meant by "too many sources" ?

How can I fix this?

[Edit]

Code:

```
import argparse
import json
import logging

import apache_beam as beam

class JsonCoder(object):
    """A JSON coder interpreting each line as a JSON string."""

    def encode(self, x):
        return json.dumps(x)

    def decode(self, x):
        return json.loads(x)

def filter_by_nonempty_county(record):
    if 'county_fips' in record and record['county_fips'] is not None:
        yield record

def run(argv=None):

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--input',
                        default='...',
                        help=('Input twitter json file specified as: '
                            'gs://path/to/tweets.json'))
    parser.add_argument(
        '--output',
        required=True,
        help=
        ('Output BigQuery table for results specified as: PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE '
        'or DATASET.TABLE.'))

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)



    p = beam.Pipeline(argv=pipeline_args)

    # read text file

    #Read all tweets from given source file
    read_tweets = "Read Tweet File" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input, coder=JsonCoder())

    #Extract the relevant fields of the source file
    extract_fields =  "Project relevant fields" >> beam.Map(lambda row: {'text': row['text'],
                                                                  'user_id': row['user']['id'],
                                                                  'location': row['user']['location'] if 'location' in row['user'] else None,
                                                                  'geo':row['geo'] if 'geo' in row else None,
                                                                  'tweet_id': row['id'],
                                                                  'time': row['created_at']})


    #check what type of geo-location the user has
    has_geo_location_or_not = "partition by has geo or not" >> beam.Partition(lambda element, partitions: 0 if element['geo'] is None else 1, 2)


    check_county_not_empty = lambda element, partitions: 1 if 'county_fips' in element and element['county_fips'] is not None else 0

    #tweet has coordinates partition or not
    coordinate_partition = (p
             | read_tweets
             | extract_fields
             | beam.ParDo(TimeConversion())
             | has_geo_location_or_not)


    #lookup by coordinates
    geo_lookup = (coordinate_partition[1] | "geo coordinates mapping" >> beam.ParDo(BeamGeoLocator())
                           | "filter successful geo coords" >> beam.Partition(check_county_not_empty, 2))

    #lookup by profile
    profile_lookup = ((coordinate_partition[0], geo_lookup[0])
                      | "join streams" >> beam.Flatten()
                      | "Lookup from profile location" >> beam.ParDo(ComputeLocationFromProfile())
                      )


    bigquery_output = "write output to BigQuery" >>  beam.io.Write(
       beam.io.BigQuerySink(known_args.output,
                   schema='text:STRING, user_id:INTEGER, county_fips:STRING, tweet_id:INTEGER, time:TIMESTAMP, county_source:STRING',
                  create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                 write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE))

    #file_output = "write output" >> beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output, coder=JsonCoder())


    output = ((profile_lookup, geo_lookup[1]) | "merge streams" >> beam.Flatten()
              | "Filter entries without location" >> beam.FlatMap(filter_by_nonempty_county)
              | "project relevant fields" >> beam.Map(lambda row: {'text': row['text'],
                                                                   'user_id': row['user_id'],
                                                                   'county_fips': row['county_fips'],
                                                                   'tweet_id': row['tweet_id'],
                                                                   'time': row['time'],
                                                                   'county_source': row['county_source']})
              | bigquery_output)

    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    run()
```

It's a little bit complicated, so it would probably take too much time to do it in bigquery directly. The code reads the tweets json, splits the PCollection by whether it's geotagged or not, if not it tries to look it up via profile location, maps to location to what's relevant for our GIS analysis and then writes it to BigQuery.

Comment: can you share your code? Also, do you have to use Beam to transform i.e could you do that in BigQuery instead i.e. load file into GCS, point BigQuery to it, and transform on the way in (or after if you prefer).

Comment: I added the code in an edit

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: The python one. Here's all the google packages currently installed: 
google-apitools (0.5.10)
google-auth (1.0.0)
google-auth-httplib2 (0.0.2)
google-cloud-bigquery (0.22.1)
google-cloud-core (0.22.1)
google-cloud-dataflow (0.6.0)
googleapis-common-protos (1.5.2)
googledatastore (7.0.0)

Comment: And the Google Cloud SDK is version 154.0.0, using the v2 Version of Dataflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of files correspond to the number of shards the elements were processed in.

One trick to reducing this is to generate some random keys, and group the elements based on that before writing them out.

For example, you could use the following `DoFn` and `PTransform` in your pipeline:

```
class _RoundRobinKeyFn(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self, count):
    self.count = count

  def start_bundle(self):
    self.counter = random.randint(0, self.count - 1)

  def process(self, element):
    self.counter += 1
    if self.counter >= self.count:
      self.counter -= self.count
    yield self.counter, element

class LimitBundles(beam.PTransform):
  def __init__(self, count):
    self.count = count

  def expand(self, input):
    return input
        | beam.ParDo(_RoundRobinKeyFn(self.count))
        | beam.GroupByKey()
        | beam.FlatMap(lambda kv: kv[1])
```

You would just use this before the bigquery_output:

```
output = (# ...
         | LimitBundles(10000)
         | bigquery_output)
```

(Note that I just typed this in without testing it, so there are likely some Python typos.)

Comment: While the solution above works, it significantly increases the runtime of a Dataflow job. In fact, lines cannot be written into Bigquery untill the whole batch is grouped by random keys. The idea of Apache Beam is to hide the low-level implementation of underlying technologies and focus on the algorithms and data pipelines. So why do we have to add additional logic to write into Bigquery using Beam's sink connector? Even for ETL jobs that do nothing more but read millions of rows from Bigquery, process them, and write back to Bigquery.